ERROR: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461
This is error I am getting, below is my YAML file.
2024-09-25 09:00:21,888 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ISPN`
2024-09-25 09:00:21,935 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
2024-09-25 09:00:21,935 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
2024-09-25 09:00:21,935 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE cdot_cms_oauth.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
2024-09-25 09:00:21,936 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE cdot_cms_oauth.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
2024-09-25 09:00:21,936 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE cdot_cms_oauth.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
2024-09-25 09:00:21,936 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE cdot_cms_oauth.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
2024-09-25 09:00:21,936 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists
2024-09-25 09:00:21,936 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

yaml file, config file for keycloak - service, deployment and persistent volume
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80                      # Standard HTTP port
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.0
          args: ["start"]
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-admin-secret  # Use a secret for admin credentials
                  key: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-admin-secret
                  key: admin-password
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "none"                     # Disable proxy settings
            - name: KC_HTTPS_ENABLED
              value: "true"  # Enable HTTPS
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
              value: "/share_data/SATHI/AUTH_API/ginni/tls.crt"  # Path to the certificate file
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
              value: "/share_data/SATHI/AUTH_API/ginni/tls.key"  # Path to the key file
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT
              value: "false"
            - name: KC_DB
              value: "mysql"  # Use MySQL
            - name: KC_DB_URL_HOST
              value: "192.168.103.59"  # Replace with your MySQL service name or hostname
            - name: KC_DB_URL_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: KC_DB_URL_DATABASE
              value: "cdot_cms_oauth"  # Your database name
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              value: "cms_oauth"
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              value: "Cdotcmsoauth@1984"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 30
          volumeMounts:                      # Correct placement of volumeMounts
            - name: keycloak-storage
              mountPath: /opt/keycloak/data   # Mount path for H2 database
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: keycloak-pvc         # Ensure you create this PVC
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: keycloak-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi                      # Adjust the storage size as needed

I have setup keycloak service, deployment in k8, getting above error. I am running this keycloak over K8.
